# Pointer gets lost in the release build

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2005

The Problem is the following:

There is the call of a constructor, where a pointer is an argument

```
 m_pszBuf= new char[260];
//Still valid , to prove i'm printing the address
    std::cout <<"Address "<< (void*)m_pszBuf <<std::endl;
    device = new Device(m_pszBuf);


Device::Device(char* _ptr){
strcpy(dest,_ptr);
}
```

Interesting is, before the call of the constructor, the pointer is still valid and has an address and value, but as soon as it entered the ctor, it becomes a bad pointer (0x0000005c). In addition, it is working in the debug mode but not in the release mode.

Comment: Well that first line isn't valid (assuming you can't convert a `Foo*` to `Foo`). We'll need to see more code. Where does `ptr` come from?

Comment: I hope you mean `Foo* f = new Foo(ptr)`

Comment: What does `ptr` point to?

Comment: post some real code please.By oversimplifying it, you/we are missing the problematic bits

Comment: just edited the code to the real content what its doing

Comment: Unless "the real code" doesn't compile due to "undeclared type: Device", etc.. its *not* "the real code". Further, since this is a dynamic member, (and Device takes it for seemingly equally evil nefarious purposes), read [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and ensure all pointer-owned resources (of which you should strive to have **none**) are properly managed and accounted for in copy constructors, assignment operators, and destructors.

Comment: Post minimal code that demonstrates your problem and still compiles.  If you knew what was unimportant and safe to eliminate you would not need to ask for help.  This does not mean post lots of code: rather trim everything you think is irrelevant, periodically confirming the problem still occurs, until you have something short yet complete. Or, write a short program you think will exhibit the problem, confirm it, then post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great input but i have solved it with something else. I had some Header files "out of sync" which were used for a library. i just needed to update them. Strange how this affected something else.

Answer (score 4):

You initialize `m_pszBuf` like this:

```
m_pszBuf = new char[260];
```

then you call `Device` constructor like this:

```
device = new Device(m_pszBuf);
```

Inside `Device` constructor, there is a `strcpy` call from `m_pszBuf` source:

```
Device::Device(char* _ptr) // _ptr == m_pszBuf
{
    strcpy(dest, _ptr);
}
```

But if `m_pszBuf` is not NUL-terminated, `strcpy` doesn't stop at the end of the allocated buffer, and it can copy garbage from out-of-bounds memory, and you can overrun the `dest` buffer.

So, before passing `m_pszBuf` to `Device` constructor, make sure that it is **NUL-terminated** and that `strcpy` destination pointer is **big enough**.

*Note*: This analysis is based just on the code snippet you showed. (I don't know if in your actual code that you omitted to show there are other problems.)

Comment: +1 this is likely spot-on. The debug-allocator commonly zero-initializes memory (which I detest as it makes finding issues like this much more difficult in debug-builds). Nice catch.

Comment: it is not about the destination, it is the source that becomes an invalid pointer inside of the constructor. It stops to point to anything.

Comment: @thebaconing: probably because `strcpy` (or something else?) overwrites it? It's hard to do _"psychic debugging"_ :) You may want to provide a compilable code snippet that shows the problem. Consider also @WhozCraig's comment about the _Rule of Three_ (or if the `Device` class doesn't have a copy semantics, declare `private` copy constructor and `operator=`). But have you tried following my suggestions and NUL-terminating `m_pszBuf`? (Or just use `memcpy` with proper size instead of `strcpy`...).

Comment: +1 @thebaconing if you ain't sure about that, replace strcpy with a char per char copy in a while/for loop and see if the problem still happens.